# How to run django server with daemontools

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-manage.py, daemontools

I am running a django webserver with default manage.py file, how can i daemonize it using svc [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html)

Content of my run file in daemontools is

```
#!/bin/bash
exec setuidgid <myuser> /usr/bin/python <path/to/manage.py> runserver 2>&1
```

Content of manage.py

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The child process(manage.py runserver) of svscanboot forks off another process in execute_from_command_line (imported from django.core.management) function, which cannot be controlled through svc commands. Below is the process tree for svscanboot.

```
/bin/sh /usr/bin/svscanboot
\_ svscan /etc/service
   \_ supervise myapp
      \_ /usr/bin/python </path/to/manage.py> runserver
          \_ /usr/bin/python </path/to/manage.py> runserver
```

Now if i execute svc -d  it sends the TERM signal to the first runserver process, and as a result just that gets killed and the second process becomes an orphan process which cannot be controlled through svc commands.

So how do i control the entire process tree of the child process using daemontools?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The server is not for production use, you shouldn't be trying to run it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by running django server with a --noreload option.

Django spawns another process only when --noreload is not passed and this is meant for dev environment only.

```
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py#L290
```

In non-dev environment you would not want the django server to get reloaded, as you wont be changing code in such environments. So running the server with --noreload solves the issue.

However it is not recommended to run default django server in production.

Comment: No it does not. It's not supposed to be used in production. You've had that comment from a leading authority on the subject.